# On cyclotomics modulo prime powers

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Regarding the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/\Phi_n(X)$ for the $n$'th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$, I find much literature on the nature of this ring taken modulo a prime $q$, that is literature on the splitting of prime ideals in Galois extensions.
But I don't understand why the analysis only concerns the splitting of *prime* ideals, not mentioning the splitting of *non-prime* ideals.

I find nothing regarding the case when $q$ is not prime. If $q$ has prime decomposition with multiplicities all $1$ then the Chinese Remainder Theorem reduces analysis back to the prime case. But what about the case when $q$ is or contains a prime power?
What is the nature of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{p^e}[X]/\Phi_n(X)$ for a prime $p$ and power $e>1$? In the case that $\Phi_n(X)$ is irreducible modulo $p$ we have a Galois ring. Where can I find literature on the more general case when $\Phi_n$ may split modulo $p$?

I'm particularly interested in the cases $p=2$, and/or $n=2^k$.
As a specific case, how do I calculate how $\Phi$ splits into irreducible in the ring
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{2^e}[X]/\Phi_{2^k}(X)
$$
with, say, $e > k$, e.g. $e=32$, $k=10$.

Comment: The structure of $O_K/\mathfrak{p}^n$ for $O_K$ the ring of integers of a number field and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal is answered by $p$-adic number theory, Hensel lemma, uniformizers, and so on. If $(p) = \prod_j \mathfrak{p}_j^{e_j}$ then $(p^r)=\prod_j \mathfrak{p}^{r e_j}$ and $O_K/(p^r) \cong \prod_j O_K/\mathfrak{p}^{r e_j}$

Comment: @reuns Helpful mentioning those topics for context. Maybe you can comment on the specific case I added at the end.

Comment: For $p$ prime and $n\ge 2$ then $\Phi_{p^r}(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}/(p^n)[x]$. This follows from looking at the $p$-adic valuation of $f(1)$ assuming that $\Phi_{p^r}(x) = f(x)g(x)$ in the monoid with cancellation $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^r}]/(p^n)[x]_{monic}$.

Comment: @reuns thank you